# Getting error while converting to current swift syntax "Cannot call value of non-function type 'XCUIElement'" in UI test cases in Xcode 8.3.2

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

Getting error while converting to current swift syntax "Cannot call value of non-function type 'XCUIElement'" in UI test cases in **Xcode 8.3.2**.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()

app.tables.cells.element(boundBy: 0).buttons.element(boundBy: 0).tap()

app.buttons.element(boundBy: 1).tap()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
elementBoundByIndex(1)
```

instead:

```
element(boundBy: 1)
```